# How to write for i in pinescript tuples?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have tuples script that working normal but I want to shorten my script by using `for i`

this is my working script ;

```
splitVolume(priceLevel) =>
    net = 0.
    if close == Price(priceLevel)
        net += volume
    [net]
[net_opt1] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe, splitVolume(1))
[net_opt2] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe, splitVolume(2))
[net_opt3] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe, splitVolume(3))
```

how to correctly write into something like this (below)?

```
for i = 1 to 3
   [net_opt(i)] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe, splitVolume(i))
```

I also have `table.cell` output that works normal, and I want to use `for i` for it too.

```
table.cell(panel, 1, 1, str.tostring(volumeOutput(net_opt1, inputTableLength), format.volume), bgcolor = color1)
table.cell(panel, 1, 2, str.tostring(volumeOutput(net_opt2, inputTableLength), format.volume), bgcolor = color1)
table.cell(panel, 1, 3, str.tostring(volumeOutput(net_opt3, inputTableLength), format.volume), bgcolor = color1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=5
indicator("stk",overlay=true)
lowerTimeframe=input.string("5")
var array<float> volArray=array.new_float(2)
for i=0 to 1
    array.set(volArray,i,0.0)

Price(p)=>
    price=0.
    if(p==1)
        price:=41510
    else if(p==2)
        price:=41500

splitVolume(priceLevel) =>
    net=array.get(volArray,priceLevel-1)
    if close == Price(priceLevel)
        net+= volume
    array.set(volArray,priceLevel-1,net)
    [net]
fn_call_request_security(priceLevel)=>
    [volNet]=request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe,splitVolume(priceLevel))
var table perfTable = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 4, border_width=1)
for i=1 to 2
    [vo]=fn_call_request_security(i)
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, i, str.tostring(vo))
```

I tried my best.. Please check this code once

Comment: Thank you, I also try to find the right way to solve it, and that ```fn_call_request_security()``` followed by other logic can work. but the next problem I had is that the output of ```str.tostring(vo)``` is 0 unless I wrote it manualy ```str.tostring(vo(1))``` ```str.tostring(vo(2))``` and so on. Do you know why?

Comment: Ideally the logic inside for loop will work for normal programming. I also need to explore more about that. As per my understanding, you are trying to accumulate the volume of specific price in a selected lower timeframe. Also for single price, it looks like its not accumulating the volume. Its is simply showing the volume of last price, if it matches with input price.

Comment: Yes you right. And it's supposed to be normal. But since tuples is used, things are a bit different for me and I have limited knowledge.

Comment: I got this warning ```The function should be called on each calculation for consistency``` and the output is not 0, its the last ```i``` output.

Comment: Hello Sir. I'm sorry. I could not find solution for this problem. I understand you are trying to find solution, like the one displayed in the following image, with maximum volume count. https://www.tradingview.com/x/OjtOrQXq/

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("stk",overlay=true)
lowerTimeframe=input.string("5")
var float net=na
splitVolume(priceLevel) =>
    request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframe, volume[priceLevel])
var table perfTable = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 4, border_width=1)
for i=1 to 3
    vo=splitVolume(i)
    table.cell(perfTable, 0, i, str.tostring(vo))
```

Please check the sample code.
Note: request.* won't work inside for or if statement. So I moved that part inside function

Comment: ```volume[priceLevel]``` will lead you to latest ```volume[i]```, I don't think this is what I'm looking for. And a tuple output suppose to be followed up with ```[variable]``` ryt?

Comment: Hi I just posted sample code, as I do not have your entire code. If you want Please modify your code as per this layout. Inside split volume you can add your logic

Comment: inside ```splitVolume()``` is a ```float```.  the logic is ```if close == 75.00``` then ```net_opt1``` has its ```net```, and the other is ```if close == 75.10``` then ```net_opt2``` has its own ```net``` and so on.

Comment: I wonder if I can generate ```[net_opt1]``` ```[net_opt2]``` ```[net_opt3]``` using ```for i```?